# How can hide form after form load?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 2 forms, in Load event of Form 1: I want open Form 2 and hide Form 1.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub FrmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
        Handles MyBase.Load
    If System.IO.File.Exists(autolog) Then    
        Dim frm As New Frm_Main
        frm.Show()
        Me.Hide()         

    End If
End Sub
```

Result: Form 2 had show, but Form 1 can't hide.

How can hide Form 1?

Comment: That's just bad.  Bad, bad, BAD!  Your `Frm_Main` should be the startup form for the project.  You should handle the `Startup` event of the application and show your login form there as a modal dialogue if and only if you need to.  If you don't show it, the startup form will be displayed as normal.  If you do show it and the login fails, you can cancel the event and the application will close without ever creating the startup form.  Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling `Me.Hide()` inside the `Load`-Method of the `Form`.

This re-shows the form after the call of `Me.Hide()` directly.

You can use the `Shown`-Event of `FrmLogin` instead.